# How to use substring and PatIndex in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to substring data. For example, I have data like this:

```
+----------------------+
|John123123412412wqeqw |
|May1231243334234wawdd |
|Jo02930124010284jahdj |
|dy827837127912938hygb |
+--------------------- +
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
+----------------------+
|John                  |
|May                   |
|Jo                    |
|dy                    |
+--------------------- +
```

As of now I don't understand how to Apply Substring and charindex in my script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are you trying to get from a string ? I mean the start and end requirement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `LEFT` and `PATINDEX` with a pattern to match the numbers like `PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 'John123123412412wqeqw')`.

Sample code

```
DECLARE @Text VARCHAR(500);
SET @Text = 'John123123412412wqeqw';

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@Text, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Text) - 1)))
```

You can do this from the table as below

```
SELECT 
   LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(ColumnName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', ColumnName) - 1))) 
FROM 
   [Table1]
```

Comment: Thanks for this @aruna. I actually get the output that what I want!

Comment: @JackyMontevirgen Great, have you used the above code or different one?

Comment: I've used the code above and it works for me. Now I Understand now the use of PATINDEX. Thanks again @Aruna :)

Comment: @JackyMontevirgen Great and you can accept the answer then :-)

Answer (score 1):

Best way to handle the strings and there manipulation is in application side and not in database side. But if you required this then you can use `PATINDEX` along with `SUBSTRING` to get what you want,

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',stringValueCol) 'Position of NonNumeric String Position',
SUBSTRING(stringValueCol,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',stringVlaueCol),PATINDEX('%[^A-Z]%',stringValueCol)-1) 'NonNumeric String'
FROM
  myTable
```

But I would still suggest do this manipulations in code and not on database side.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @coder of code. But I  don't use any application. I want only to extract raw data from my database and put it my report.But your suggestion helps also. thanks again!