# Extract parts of string separated by delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is an add on to my original question: [Variable length substring between two characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800783/variable-length-substring-between-two-characters/65800793#65800793)

The data often looks like this, all in one column:

```
Growth: Compliance;Priority: Contractual;Original Vendor: ABC SERVICES;
```

In the above example:

- "Compliance" (NOT "Growth: Compliance") needs to be extracted and stored in the `GROWTH_TXT` column
- "Contractual" needs to be extracted and stored in the `PRIORITY_TXT` column
- "Original Vendor: ABC Services" can be ignored because it's not stored anywhere

Comment: Maybe try patindex. Example with substring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924008/how-to-use-substring-and-patindex-in-sql-server

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? And does your string always have the same structure, order, and number of elements?

Comment: @PhilCoulson I updated my compatibility to 130 (it was 110). And no, the string length is variable, the sample given above is just one. It could also be "Growth: Run; Priority: Critical - Turns Contractual". And not every line has "Original Vendor" at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2016+

Concept using STRING_SPLIT(), PARSENAME(), PIVOT

```sql
-- Mimic Table named z_tbl_tmp
DECLARE @z_tbl_tmp TABLE (id INT, OPTIONAL_FIELD_1 NVARCHAR(max));
INSERT INTO @z_tbl_tmp VALUES (1, N'Growth: Compliance;Priority: Contractual;Original Vendor: ABC SERVICES;');
INSERT INTO @z_tbl_tmp VALUES (2, N'Growth: Run; Priority: Critical - Turns Contractual');
-- 

-- Pivot Parsed Data
WITH tbl_parsed AS (
    -- Parse Data into Key Value Pairs
    SELECT id, 
        TRIM(PARSENAME(REPLACE(value,': ','.'), 2)) AS K, 
        TRIM(PARSENAME(REPLACE(value,': ','.'), 1)) AS V 
    FROM @z_tbl_tmp
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(OPTIONAL_FIELD_1,';')
)
SELECT id, [Growth] AS GROWTH_TXT, [Priority] AS PRIORITY_TXT
FROM tbl_parsed
    PIVOT (MAX(V) FOR [K] IN ([Growth], [Priority])) AS pvt
```

```
+----+------------+-------------------------------+
| id | GROWTH_TXT | PRIORITY_TXT                  |
+----+------------+-------------------------------+
|  1 | Compliance | Contractual                   |
+----+------------+-------------------------------+
|  2 | Run        | Critical - Turns Contractual  |
+----+------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi @vhoang, I like this, but this will be come from a table as part of an ETL and not a declared table as written. My table name is z_tbl_tmp and the column name that the values are stored in is called OPTIONAL_FIELD_1. So I'm struggling a little bit translating the above.

Comment: The first two statements is an attempt to create sample data that looks like what you have.   I've updated based on the new info provided.  Remove the @ symbol in front of the z_tbl_tmp and change id to a primary key field in you table if you have one.   It's a self contained test unit that lets us test without having a physical table.

Comment: Saw the extra data example in the first post comment.   Updated query to cover it.   Also PARSENAME uses periods as a delimiter.   I didn't spot any in your sample's structure so it's not accounted for, but if you have some in your data, you can swap the original period out to something that is not in the data like a "|" and back, before and after PARSENAME.

Answer (score 1):

From SQL Server 2016, a combination of `STRING_SPLIT()`, `PATINDEX()` and conditional aggregation is an option:

```
DECLARE @text varchar(1000) = 'Growth: Compliance;Priority: Contractual;Original Vendor: ABC SERVICES;'

SELECT 
   MAX(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('Growth:%', [value]) = 1 THEN STUFF([value], 1, LEN('Growth:'), '') END) AS GROWTH_TXT,
   MAX(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('Priority:%', [value]) = 1 THEN STUFF([value], 1, LEN('Priority:'), '') END) AS PRIORITY_TXT
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@text, ';')
```

Result:

```
GROWTH_TXT  PRIORITY_TXT
 Compliance  Contractual
```

If the data is stored in a table, you need an additional `APPLY` operator:

```
DECLARE @text varchar(1000) = 'Growth: Compliance;Priority: Contractual;Original Vendor: ABC SERVICES;'
SELECT @text AS OPTIONAL_FIELD_1
INTO z_tbl_temp

SELECT a.*
FROM z_tbl_temp z
OUTER APPLY ( 
   SELECT 
      MAX(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('Growth:%', [value]) = 1 THEN STUFF([value], 1, LEN('Growth:'), '') END) AS GROWTH_TXT,
      MAX(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('Priority:%', [value]) = 1 THEN STUFF([value], 1, LEN('Priority:'), '') END) AS PRIORITY_TXT
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(z.OPTIONAL_FIELD_1, ';')
) a
```

Comment: Hi @zhorov, I like this example and it works like I expect (now that I upgraded my DB compatibility to 130 :D). This will be part of a stored procedure and so the values will come from a column in a table and not from a declared variable text string. So if my column name is OPTIONAL_FIELD_1 and my table name is z_tbl_temp, how would I write the above. Sorry to be so needy :D

Answer (score 0):

Another approach based on JSON.

SQL Server 2016/2017 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, val NVARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(N'Growth: Compliance;Priority: Contractual;Original Vendor: ABC SERVICES;')
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ';'
    , @separatorJson CHAR(3) = '","'
    , @colon CHAR(2) = ': '
    , @colonJson CHAR(3) = '":"';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT id
          , N'{"' + 
             REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(';' FROM val),@colon, @colonJson), @separator, @separatorJson) + 
                N'"}' AS DataJson
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT id
    , JSON_VALUE(DataJson, N'$.Growth') AS [Growth]
    , JSON_VALUE(DataJson, N'$.Priority') AS [Priority]
    , JSON_VALUE(DataJson, N'$."Original Vendor"') AS [Original Vendor]
FROM rs;
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------+-------------+-----------------+
| id |   Growth   |  Priority   | Original Vendor |
+----+------------+-------------+-----------------+
|  1 | Compliance | Contractual | ABC SERVICES    |
+----+------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

For SQL Server 2016 because it doesn't support updated `TRIM()` function:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(val,LEN(val)-1),@colon, @colonJson), @separator, @separatorJson) +
```

Comment: SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: You never answered a simple question: What is the SQL Server version? `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: I updated answer for SQL Server 2016. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If the string column follows a consistent pattern, something along these lines should do it.

```
with cte(str,i1,i2,i3) as

(select str, 
        charindex('Growth: ',str), 
        charindex('Priority: ',str), 
        charindex('Original Vendor: ',str)
 from your_table) 

 select substring(str,i1+8,i2-i1-9), substring(str,i2+9,i3-i2-10) 
 from cte;
```

The arithmetic with 8, 9 and 10 in the `substring` is to get rid of unwanted characters that I assumed to be fixed in size.

---

Another method uses `string_split` with a `cross apply`

```
select str, 
       replace(min(value),'Growth: ','') growth_txt,
       replace(max(value),'Priority: ','') as priority_txt
from your_table
cross apply string_split(str,';')
where value like 'Growth: %' or value like 'Priority: %'
group by str;
```

Since letter G comes before letter P, the use of `min` and `max` ensures the `replace` function is being used on the right string. The way @Zhorov's answer handles that is probably more reliable in case you decide to parse a different set of elements and you don't want to think too much about the alphabetical order.