How to retrieve data between pipes (delimiter) in string
I have a single table called #ParsedBlocks that contains one column called [BlockData].
This column contains a string that's pipe delimited.
I need to return the data between the pipe characters into separate columns.
So I've figured out how to extract the first column with the below script but I can't figure out how to extract from the second column onwards
select * 
    ,SUBSTRING(BlockData, 1, CHARINDEX('|',BlockData) -1)
    ,SUBSTRING(BlockData, CHARINDEX('|', BlockData) + 1, LEN(BlockData))
from 
    #ParsedBlocks

The result of the above script:



Column1
Column2




SiteCode1
ItemCode1


SiteCode1
ItemCode2



Source Dataset:



BlockData




SiteCode1


SiteCode1



Required Result:



Column1
Column2
Column3
Column4




Sitecode1
ItemCode1
NULL
CostPrice1


Sitecode1
ItemCode2
NULL
CostPrice2



I have a couple of these ParsedBlocks tables that I need to apply this logic to and each table has a different number of pipe delimiters (columns) so it would be great if there was a way to have a single script to easily apply to each table.
For example:
Having a script that "automatically" finds each pipe (column) and returns the data accordingly, if that makes sense...

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

You can check out string split function that would convert your column into rows.  You can do a join on the parsed out column.

You source example doesn't contain any pipes, making your question somewhat confusing. But in general, you can't create dynamic columns in sql server, either you spell them out using pivot or you write some dynamic code which spells them out for you. This hasa been done gazillion of times, search for PIVOT or conditiona aggregation, and STRING_SPLIT for the splitting per row

Where does the value 'CostPrice1' come from? It's not in your sample data

Does this answer your question? How to split a comma-separated value to columns

Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65851456/extract-parts-of-string-separated-by-delimiter

Why are you trying to do this in SQL (in the back-end)? String.Split functions in in the front-end are so much easier to use.

@siggemannen, seems like Stackoverflow table markup doesn't like vertical bar symbol so it removed it :(

@OlivierJacot-Descombes, please elaborate? excuse my ignorance

I don't know which language you are using to create your application. Java, VB, C#, Python, ...? In these languages there are more comfortable means to achieve such things and SQL would only be used to deliver the raw data to your application. And with O/R-mappers you can even do without SQL altogether.

Just another option using a bit of JSON
 Select Pos1 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
       ,Pos2 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
       ,Pos3 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
       ,Pos4 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[3]')
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape([BlockData],'json'),'|','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)

Results
Pos1        Pos2        Pos3    Pos4
Sitecode1   ItemCode1           CostPrice1
Sitecode1   ItemCode2           CostPrice2


This also works beautifully. Thanks for the help!

Please try the following conceptual solution that is using tokenization via SQL Server's XML and XQuery.
You can add as many as needed output columns in the SELECT clause.
The absolutely dynamic solution will require a dynamic SQL.
Stackoverflow table markup doesn't like vertical bar symbol that why I replaced it with the slash in the Output section.
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, BlockData VARCHAR(1024));
INSERT INTO @tbl (BlockData) VALUES
('Sitecode1|ItemCode1||CostPrice1'),
('Sitecode1|ItemCode2||CostPrice2');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '|';

SELECT *
    , c.value('(/root/r[1]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS col1
    , c.value('(/root/r[2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS col2
    , c.value('(/root/r[3]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS col3
    , c.value('(/root/r[4]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS col4
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(BlockData, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);

Output



id
BlockData
col1
col2
col3
col4




1
Sitecode1/ItemCode1//CostPrice1
Sitecode1
ItemCode1
NULL
CostPrice1


2
Sitecode1/ItemCode2//CostPrice2
Sitecode1
ItemCode2
NULL
CostPrice2




This works perfectly! thank you for the help much appreciated

Use PARSENAME function
PARSENAME - Returns the specified part of an object name.  It is handy addition to your TSQL toolkit when writing queries involving delimited data.
SYNTAX:
PARSENAME(object_name, object_piece)

FOR EXAMPLE
Declare @BlockData VARCHAR(1000);
--PARSENAME function only use a period(.) as the delimiter to split on.
Set @BlockData= 'Sitecode1.ItemCode1..CostPrice1';

SELECT
        PARSENAME(@BlockData, 4) as Column1,
        PARSENAME(@BlockData, 3) as Column2,
        PARSENAME(@BlockData, 2) as Column3,
        PARSENAME(@BlockData, 1) as Column4;

it will return



Column1
Column2
Column3
Column4




Sitecode1
ItemCode1
Null
CostPrice1



in our case we will use REPLACE function to change the delimiter from '|' to '.'
In above example, PARSENAME returns ‘costprice1’, which is the first part of the object name when counting from right to left.
Finally we can do the following
CREATE TABLE #ParsedTable (BlockData VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #ParsedTable (BlockData) 
VALUES ('Sitecode1|ItemCode1||CostPrice1'),
('Sitecode1|ItemCode2||CostPrice2');

SELECT 
PARSENAME(REPLACE(BlockData,'|','.'),4) as Column1, 
PARSENAME(REPLACE(BlockData,'|','.'),3) as Column2,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(BlockData,'|','.'),2) as Column3,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(BlockData,'|','.'),1) as Column4
FROM 
#ParsedTable ;

DROP TABLE #ParsedTable;

The result set will return



Column1
Column2
Column3
Column4




Sitecode1
ItemCode1
Null
CostPrice1


Sitecode1
ItemCode2
Null
CostPrice2



I implemented it on SQL Server 2014 express, SQL Server 2016 and SQL Server 2019.
Limitations: The specified string can only have 4 parts. If you try using PARSENAME to split the string 'Sitecode1.ItemCode1..CostPrice1.MarketPrice' you will get a null value returned.
Thank you.

My first thought as well.   I never understood why you can't define the delimiter.   Seems like a missed opportunity.   That said, one has to be sure that no other periods or decimals in the string.   +1
